SOLR 8.11.1 SSL Enable Failing
I’m trying to enable SSL on SOLR 8.11.1
My network team purchased a certificate
Imported into JDK into a file cacerts
I copied that file to etc/solr-ssl.keystore.p12
I uncommented the SOLR SSL changed solr.in.cmd and set them as follows:
REM Enables HTTPS. It is implictly true if you set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE. Use this config
REM to enable https module with custom jetty configuration.
set SOLR_SSL_ENABLED=true
REM Uncomment to set SSL-related system properties
REM Be sure to update the paths to the correct keystore for your environment
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.p12
set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=-----------------
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.p12
set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=-----------------
REM Require clients to authenticate
set SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false
REM Enable clients to authenticate (but not require)
set SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false
REM Verify client hostname during SSL handshake
set SOLR_SSL_CLIENT_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION=false
REM SSL Certificates contain host/ip "peer name" information that is validated by default. Setting
REM this to false can be useful to disable these checks when re-using a certificate on many hosts
set SOLR_SSL_CHECK_PEER_NAME=true
REM Override Key/Trust Store types if necessary
REM set SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=PKCS12
REM set SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE=PKCS12

I thin started solr from the command line, and this is what I saw:
E:\ApacheSolr8_11_1>bin\solr.cmd start -p 8983
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: JVM cannot use large page memory because it does not have enough privilege to lock pages in memory.
INFO  - 2024-05-06 17:05:17.952; org.apache.solr.util.configuration.SSLConfigurations; Setting javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
INFO  - 2024-05-06 17:05:17.967; org.apache.solr.util.configuration.SSLConfigurations; Setting javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
Waiting up to 30 to see Solr running on port 8983
INFO  - 2024-05-06 17:05:27.966; org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec; I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://localhost:8983: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
INFO  - 2024-05-06 17:05:27.966; org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec; Retrying request to {s}->https://localhost:8983
INFO  - 2024-05-06 17:05:30.014; org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec; I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://localhost:8983: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
INFO  - 2024-05-06 17:05:30.014; org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec; Retrying request to {s}->https://localhost:8983
INFO  - 2024-05-06 17:05:34.087; org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec; I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://localhost:8983: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
INFO  - 2024-05-06 17:05:34.087; org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec; Retrying request to {s}->https://localhost:8983
INFO  - 2024-05-06 17:05:34.103; org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec; I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://localhost:8983: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

I've tried different combinations of SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH and SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH but the get the same result.
The log doesnt show any error messages about SSL.
Is there something obvious I'm missing? Any suggestions?
